# Plugin Stylesheet 404

Tags: plugin-development, assets, css

Hey guys I have created a plugin with an accompanying Stylesheet which I am adding to the page via

```
class SitemaphtmlPlugin extends BasePlugin
{

function init(){

     craft()->templates->includeCssResource('sitemaphtml/css/sitemaphtml.css');
}
```

however the link being generated is prefixing the path with cpresources/ making it 404.

```
/cpresources/sitemaphtml/css/sitemaphtml.css?x=xXhFyszUs
```

how can i overcome this this?

Cheers

Comment: Are you trying to get the CSS file to load in the control panel or on the front-end of a site?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I am trying to get the CSS to load on the front-end of the site. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your css file located in the `/resources/` folder of your plugin? So your path should be something like:

```
<plugin folder>/resources/css/sitemaphtml.css
```

I've tried it myself and whilst you do get the `/cpresources/` part of the Url in your markup, the CSS file is loaded on the front end.

EDIT: If you take a look in the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/resources), it says the following:

> By default, Craft will search for the resource file in its own
>   craft/app/resources/ folder. If it can’t find the file there, it will
>   check if the first segment of the resource path is set to a plugin
>   handle. If it is, Craft will look for the resource file within that
>   plugin’s resources/ folder.

Comment: That was it all along, thank oyu very much for your help.

Comment: No worries, I've done it myself :)